# How to use Array.copy(Array,long,array,long,long) in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

Iam new to c#. 
i am working in c# project. 
iam using Array.Copy()  function But it giving the compile time error that invalid arguments atArray.Copy();
 method can any body to solve that invalid arguments. error.

```
int N=50;
    int M=N*2;
    int[,] amn = new int[M,N];
    //for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
    //Arrays.fill(amn[i], 0);
    int[] a=new int[2];
    int[] b=new int[2];
    a[0]=1;b[1]=1;

    for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<N/2;j++)
        {
            if(i%2==0)
                Array.Copy(a, 0, amn[i], j*2, 2);
            else
                Array.Copy(b, 0, amn[i], j*2, 2);
        }

    }
```

Comment: @down voters If you know answer tell. why down votes are giving

Comment: I suspect you are downvoted because you don't say on what line are you getting your error, and you don't say *exactly* what the error message is. The latter in particular is important because, if you were to read and understand it, it will explain the reason your code is failing to compile.

Comment: error is coming at Array.copy(a, 0, amn[i], j*2, 2); error is insufficient arguments

Comment: I mean System.arraycopy() equivalent method in c#

Comment: The error is not "insufficient arguments" - the error will be more descriptive than that. Copy and past the *exact* and *complete* text of the error. Or, since you have two answers that suggest the same thing, try what they suggest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since `amn` is [*2 dimensional array*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx), `amn[i]` in an `int` on this case not array. In fact, it doesn't allow to use without define second diamension.

Your `Array.Copy` takes an array as a third parameter.

As an alternative, you can use [*jagged arrays*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) if you want to process on arrays.

Comment: I mean System.arraycopy() equivalent method in c#

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for similar to java function like system.arraycopy in C#...then use
System.Array.ConstrainedCopy.

description: Copies a range of elements from an Array starting at the specified source index and pastes them to another Array starting at the specified destination index. Guarantees that all changes are undone if the copy does not succeed completelay.